# Is statsmodels lagmatrix function "wrong" ? (adds zeros to lagged array)

Tags: python, statsmodels

**Example:**

Python

```
lagmatrix([1 2 3])
returns [0 1 2]
```

This is obviously not correct if I want to regress Y against the lagged values of Y (i.e. an AR process).

I want to run a regress of Y and the lag values of Y using statsmodel.OLS but if I put NaN in the lagged verison of Y, OLS complains and doesn't run.

Is there a way to run the regression without regressing `Y[1:-1]` against `lagmatrix(Y)[1:-1]` ?

If I have more lags this can get annoying.

How does the AR function in statsmodels find lags?

Comment: You can use missing='drop' to drop NaNs without raising an error, but you should use the 'trim' argument of lagmat or one of the ready-made models for lagged dependent variables described below.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your `lagmatrix` is.

I would recommend using pandas, which has a lag method and has nan handling.

statsmodels has two functions that are used internally to create the lag matrices for autoregressive and vector autoregressive models and for related hypothesis tests, which have a `trim` option to choose how to treat initial and trailing observations.

```
>>> from statsmodels.tsa.tsatools import lagmat, lagmat2ds
>>> x = np.arange(10)
>>> y_lagged, y = lagmat(x, maxlag=2, trim="forward", original='sep')
>>> y_lagged
array([[ 0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.],
       [ 2.,  1.],
       [ 3.,  2.],
       [ 4.,  3.],
       [ 5.,  4.],
       [ 6.,  5.],
       [ 7.,  6.],
       [ 8.,  7.]])
>>> y
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4],
       [5],
       [6],
       [7],
       [8],
       [9]])
>>> y_lagged, y = lagmat(x, maxlag=2, trim="both", original='sep')
>>> y_lagged
array([[ 1.,  0.],
       [ 2.,  1.],
       [ 3.,  2.],
       [ 4.,  3.],
       [ 5.,  4.],
       [ 6.,  5.],
       [ 7.,  6.],
       [ 8.,  7.]])
>>> y
array([[2],
       [3],
       [4],
       [5],
       [6],
       [7],
       [8],
       [9]])
```

Comment: I would also add to this comment to explore the 'trim' option of lagmat, that you should look at using `sm.tsa.AR`, `sm.tsa.ARMA`, or `sm.tsa.ARIMA` instead of using OLS yourself and making the lagged values. These all handle the lags for you and the estimators. Is there something missing in AR/AR(I)MA models that you need?

Comment: I want to run a multiple regression with lagged values of Y and other dependent variables (x1, ..,xn). So ARIMA would not suffice.